# I can't use if..else statements in multiple condtions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Super beginner. I'm doing a contact form using Javascript, Json and for backend PHP. I can't get the conditionals to work when some fields are left empty, then all alert messages come one after another.

I've tried using "else" after every if statement but it only works for the couple of first conditions.

```
      if(result.validAllEmpty == "allEmpty"){ 
         alert("Name, Email and Message are required");
             $("#yname").css({"border":"5px solid red"});
             $("#nameSpan").text(" must only contain letters and 
                whitespace, ex.\"John Doe\"");
             $("#yemail").css({"border": "5px solid red"});
             $("#emailSpan").text("  please enter a valid email address, 
               ex.\"paulo@brazil.com\"");
             $("#ymessage").css({"border":"10px solid red"});
             $("#messageSpan").text("please type something, anything");



        } else {



        if(result.validFormName == "empty" && result.validFormEmail == "empty"){
          alert("Name and Email are required");
           $("#yname").css({"border":"5px solid red"});
            $("#nameSpan").text(" must only contain letters and whitespace, ex.\"John Doe\"");
            $("#yemail").css({"border": "5px solid red"});
            $("#emailSpan").text("  please enter a valid email address, ex.\"paulo@brazil.com\"");


        } 

         if(result.validFormName == "empty"){
            alert("Name is required");
          $("#yname").css({"border":"5px solid red"});
          $("#nameSpan").text(" must only contain letters and whitespace, ex.\"John Doe\"");

        }

         if(result.validFormEmail == "empty"){
          alert("Email is required");
          $("#yemail").css({"border": "10px solid red"});
          $("emailSpan").text("please enter a valid email address, ex.\"paulo@brazil.com\"");

          }   

        if(result.validFormName == "empty" && result.validFormMessage == "empty"){
            alert("Name and Message are required");
            $("#yname").css({"border":"5px solid red"});
            $("#nameSpan").text("must only contain letters and whitespace");
            $("#ymessage").css({"border":"10px solid red"});
            $("#messageSpan").text("type something, anything");

        }    

         if(result.validFormEmail == "empty" && result.validFormMessage == "empty"){
            alert("Email and Message are required");
          $("#yemail").css({"border": "5px solid red"});
          $("#emailSpan").text(" required  please enter your email address");
          $("#ymessage").css({"border": "10px solid red"});
          $("#messageSpan").text("write something, anything..");

        }        

          if(result.validFormMessage == "empty"){
          alert("Message is required");
          $("#ymessage").css({"border": "10px solid red"});
          $("#messageSpan").text(" write something, anything");

        }


SOME PHP

    } else { 
               //validate all empty
           if (empty ($name) && empty ($email) && empty ($message)){
                $export['validAllEmpty'] = "allEmpty";
           }
                if (empty($name)){

                    $export['validFormName'] = "empty";

                    } else { 

                    $export['validFormName'] = "notEmpty";

                    }

                if (empty($email)){

                    $export['validFormEmail'] = "empty";

                    } else {

                    $export['validFormEmail'] ="notEmpty";

                    } 

                if (empty($message)){

                    $export['validFormMessage'] = "empty";

                } else {

                $export['validFormMessage'] = "notEmpty";

                } 
         }

        }   

       echo json_encode($export);

     }





?>
```

I'd like the alert messages to show only for the relevant condition and not show in a row, one after another. Also, is there a way to make this code more simple? Sorry, if the post and code are messy. My first time posting here. I'd appreciate any help.Thank you

Comment: You can't mix JavaScript and PHP like this.

Comment: You can't wrap strings over multiple lines in JavaScript.

Comment: Have each validation check concatenate an error message onto a string. At the end, if the string is not empty, display it in an alert.

Comment: If you populate your `$export` PHP variable, you can pass it for use in JS like so: `var someJsonObject = <?php echo json_encode($export); ?>;`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Do you mean mixing in the same file? They are not in the same one if that's what you're asking. Do you mean I can't wrap "empty" strings like this? Sorry if I'm asking the obvious

Comment: Thanks mtr.web although I'm not sure I understand

Comment: If they're not mixed in one file, I don't understand your code. You start with a JavaScript `if`, then you have PHP code in the `else` block.

Comment: I thought before "Some PHP" line I only have Javascript. I have just one "else" statement which helps me pass the first condition (ValidateAllEmpty) but after "else" all of the alerts show. For example, if on my contact form I leave both Name and Email empty, then submit, the alert for those two empty fields will show followed by the alert for empty Name and empty Email. So I have three alerts where I just  need one. (Name and Email are required). They seem to work but all at once

Comment: You should try googling `Mix PHP and Javascript`..  [Here is one example source](http://www.howtoplaza.com/how-to-mix-javascript-and-php)

Comment: Thanks, the blog post was helpful